# How Can I combine the equations' results in a table without "x->"

Tags: replacement, list-manipulation

For example: I have a series of functions:
`F[x_,o_]=x+o`
And I want to combine the result into a table with o=0.3,0.6,0.9..

```
Table[Solve[F[x, o] == 0, x], {o, 0.1, 1, 0.3}]
```

The results is obvious {{{x -> -0.1}}, {{x -> -0.4}}, {{x -> -0.7}}, {{x -> -1.}}}

How can I automatically transform the results to a table like this?
{-0.1,-0.4,-0.7,-1.}

Comment: `Table[x /. First@Solve[F[x, o] == 0, x], {o, 0.1, 1, 0.3}]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I never thought "First" could solve this problem.!

Comment: Or, `x /. Flatten[Table[(* stuff *)]]`